# How can I get all the account addresses owned by a program?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I am trying to get all the addresses than are owned by a particular program on Solana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered it in another question. Please check this link out -
https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2531/486

Answer (score 0):

Please use GPA for that, keep in mind it's a very slow and expensive call.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getProgramAccounts